# Beginner Help: Looking for Member Names in diffrent projects to see in which projects they are working together

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am very new to SQL. I have done some basic "select from where ..." queries but I struggle with my current project.

Lets say this is my source table:

```
Project     Involved
1           Harald
1           Kerstin
1           Peter
1           Christian
1           Lisa
1           Linda
2           Sören
2           Schmidt
2           Jörg
2           Robert
2           Harald
2           Lisa
```

My question should be fairly simple. The input is the name "Lisa" and "Harald". I want to know "Which projects are Lisa and Harald involved in"

If this is super easy and cannot understand why I ask such easy thing: provide me with a link where this is explained and ill read trough it myself, just not so sure what exactly to look for so I thought this was a faster way to get started :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this in many ways, but here is the primary way I would solve it... but start simply for what projects LISA is associated with...  This prevents looking at what could be 1000s of projects / people but if Lisa is only associated with 5 (or 2 in this case), why query against all of them..

```
Select
      p1.project
   from
      project p1
   where
      p1.involved = 'Lisa'
```

So this lists projects 1 & 2 (obviously your short sample of data.  Now, that we know this works, I would just JOIN again for Harold and the same project as this.

```
Select
      p1.project
   from
      project p1
         join project p2
            on p1.project = p2.project
           AND p2.involved = 'Harold'
   where
      p1.involved = 'Lisa'
```

Ensure you have an index on (involved, project) to help optimize the query

Additionally, others may propose to do a group by and having clause based on both parties you are interested in.... something like

```
select
      p1.project
   from
      project p1
   where
      p1.involved in ( 'Lisa', 'Harold')
   group by
      p1.project
   having 
      count(*) = 2
```

This basically says to the engine. Give me each project where either Lisa or Harold exist.  But, by applying a group by I only want the project to show once so I don't see duplicates.  The HAVING clause tells how many you EXPECT to have per project, and since you are asking for 2 possible names, and want both of them, the HAVING COUNT(*) is 2 so you know BOTH are included.

Answer (score 0):

I've named table as person, so this is the example

```
SELECT
    p1.project
FROM
    person p1,
    person p2
WHERE
    p1.name = 'Harald'
AND p2.name = 'Lisa'
AND p1.project = p2.project
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. But wouldnt this say

"Show me the project from projects where either Lisa or Harald are involved"? I need to find out the intersection. In my example this would be project 1 and project 2 as both harald and lisa are involved in each of these projects.

Answer (score 0):

To see the projects which *both* Lisa and Harald are involed in:

```
SELECT P1.Project FROM
(SELECT Project FROM MyTable WHERE Involved = 'Lisa') P1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT Project FROM MyTable WHERE Involved = 'Harald') P2
WHERE P1.Project = P2.Project
```